# Best way to simplify edges of a pixely mask?

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I'm working on an experimental video that uses a mask of a person.   Some of the masks were made in After Effects using the roto brush tool at full resolution, as is recommended.

Some however were not and done at a much lower res.  The result is naturally masks with visible pixel notches in them as you can see below.

[image]

Ideally within Premiere Pro where I'm editing the video, are there any reliable ways to simplify the mask edge ?

Comment: Those edges don’t look like they need sharpening. They’re probably jagged because of a mistake with premultiplication, which tells the computer whether or not semi-transparent pixels include information from the background upon which they were originally shot, in a nutshell.

Comment: You are quite right, sharpening is not the best word. I'm going to change the title of the question.